# What is the category of covariant and contravariant functors?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\bf Cat'$ be the category that has as objects small categories $A, B...$, and as arrows functors $F:A\to B$ that are either covariant or contravariant. The identity on $A\in\bf Cat'$ is the usual identity functor; the composition of a covariant and a contravariant functor is contravariant and the composition of two contravariant functors is covariant. (Here, by a contravariant functor $F:A\to B$, I mean a mapping $F: obj A \to obj B$ and for any arrow $f:x\to y$ an arrow $Ff:Fy\to Fx$ with the usual axioms on identities and composition.)

I wonder which are the abstract properties of $\bf Cat'$.
Note for instance that in $\bf Cat'$ any category is isomorphic to its dual; so I suppose that it is not possible to recover the covariant arrows in an abstract way. Maybe the obvious functor $\bf Cat \to \bf Cat'$ has some universal property?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\mathbf{Cat'}$ can be thought of as a semi-direct product. There is an action $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbf{Cat}$ given be the oposite category endofunctor and $\mathbf{Cat'}$ is isomorphic to the semi-direct product $G \ltimes \mathbf{Cat}$.

In general the semi-direct product $G \ltimes C$ of a category $C$ by a group $G$ acting on $C$, is the category whose objects are the $c \in C$ and the morphisms $x \to y$ are pair $(g,f)$ where $g$ is an element of $G$ and $f$ is an arrow $x \to gy$, composition being given by $(g,f) \circ (g',f') = (gg',f \circ gf')$.

In our case, morphisms of the form $(0,f)$ are covariant functor, while the $(1,f)$ are the contravariant functors !

Semi-direct product are also a special case of the Grothendieck construction: the action of $G$ on $C$ can be described as a functor $BG \to \mathbf{Cat}$ where $BG$ is the one object groupoid with $G$ has its unique automorphism group. And the semi-direct product described above is the corresponding Grothendieck construction.

Now, this Grothendieck construction point of view provide us with a universal property for the semi-direct product: *The Grothendieck construction is the Lax colimit of a diagram.* Here, given that $BG$ only has invertible cell, this is also the pseudo-colimit of the diagram $BG \to \mathbf{Cat}$. That is it is the "pseudo-quotient" of $C$ by the action of $G$.

Comming back to the action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, this means that $\mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Cat'}$ is universal for making the action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ trivial, in an appropriate 2-categorical sense.

If you prefer, the functor from the $2$-category of categories to the $2$-category of categories with an action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has a left 2-adjoint $Q$, and if $\mathbf{Cat}$ is endowed with its action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by the opposite category, then (up to equivalence of categories) $\mathbf{Cat'} \simeq Q(\mathbf{Cat})$.

Comment: I'm wondering which are the completeness properties of $\bf Cat'$. For instance, there seems to be no terminal object; in fact, in $\bf Cat'$ there are two morphisms to the terminal category: one covariant and one contravariant. And the same problem holds for the initial object.

Comment: I also don't think there is a terminal objects and I don't quite see either how product or coproduct would work. My guess would be that the point of view of Mike Shulman's answer might be better suited for this... the category should have enriched limits/colimits when considered as an enriched category in the way described by Mike.

Answer (score 5):

You may also be interested in my paper [Contravariance through enrichment](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/5/33-05abs.html), which shows that $\bf Cat'$ is enriched over a certain non-symmetric monoidal structure on $\bf Cat\times Cat$.  This allows distinguishing the covariant and contravariant functors while still keeping them both present in the structure.  Thus for instance we can distinguish the "contravariant isomorphism" $A\cong A^{\rm op}$ from a normal covariant isomorphism, and indeed use the former to characterize $A^{\rm op}$ as "the unique (up to covariant isomorphism) object contravariantly isomorphic to $A$", which is also a copower of $A$ in the sense of enriched category theory.

This structure is actually closely related to the construction in Simon's answer; the monoidal structure on $\bf Cat\times Cat$ is constructed using the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action on $\bf Cat$, and can be generalized to other group actions.

Also I should note that when I say $\bf Cat'$ "is" enriched over $\bf Cat\times Cat$, I don't mean in the precise sense that $\bf Cat'$ is the "underlying ordinary category" of an enriched category in the standard sense of enriched category theory; the underlying ordinary category of the enriched form of $\bf Cat'$ is actually just $\bf Cat$.  This is similar to the situation of group actions, where a category enriched over $G$-sets is a category with $G$-actions on its hom-sets, but the "underlying ordinary category" takes the fixed-point sets of those hom-sets (rather than, for instance, forgetting the $G$-actions).

Comment: maybe, as suggested by Simon, that your approach gives some hints on the completeness of $\bf Cat'$? (see the comments above)

Comment: Yes, I expect it should have some limits and colimits as an enriched category.  At least, conical ones, as well as the copowers I mentioned (which are also powers, since the object in question is dualizable).  I doubt that it is complete and cocomplete as an enriched category, though: there are so many weird objects of $\bf Cat \times Cat$ that it seems unlikely $\bf Cat'$ would have powers and copowers by them all.